# Trying to show two different images depending on two media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm here with a problem that I don't see how I can solve it.

I have a header "topo" with a image.

And I want that image in my desktop and tablet versions, but in my media query for smartphone with 480px I want to show other image, a smaller image.

So in my 480px media query, I'm trying to give background-image with CSS and make my #logo image as `display:none`, so I can have my smaller image for smartphone.

But it's not working, can somebody there give me a little help?

This is my html for this issue:

```
<header id="topo">
    <span id="logo">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png" /></a>
    </span>
</header>
```

I have this media query for mobile

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) 
{

*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:none;
}

body
{
    min-width:320px;
}

#topo
{
    width:226px;
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    background:url(../imagens/logo%20-%20C%C3%B3pia.png);   
}

.....
}
```

This is my media query for tablet:

```
@media screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px) 
{

*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:none;
}

#topo
{
    width:700px;
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    background:yellow;  
}

#logo
{
    float:left;

}

....

}
```

Comment: Please explain not working part, ie which image is displaying in desktop and which one in smartphone. Also provide your smartphone screen size and orientation

Comment: The image I want in desktop and tablet ins the image I have in my html content "logo.png", and In smartphone with 480px media querie I want to show other image that is this:  background:url(../imagens/logo%20-%20C%C3%B3pia.png);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, when you set `display:none` on the `img` element, the `a` element collapses upon itself because the `img` element is the `a` element's only child. The background image is therefore not displayed because the `a` element has a height of `0`. To solve this, you should set a height on the `a` element and change the element's `display` from `inline` to `block`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/79Gdu/)

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    #topo {
        width:226px;
        margin:10px auto 0 auto;
        background:url('//placehold.it/200/0ff');
    }
    #topo a {
        height:200px;
        display:block;
    }
    #topo img {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

The above solution may work for a majority of scenarios, however, if you want to avoid setting a height on the element, i'd suggest doing something like this instead:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bRX2c/)

Add both `img` elements into the markup, giving each mutually exclusive classes.

```
<a href="index.php">
    <img class="hidden_mobile" src="//placehold.it/200/000" />
    <img class="hidden_desktop" src="//placehold.it/200/f00" />
</a>
```

Use something along these lines and hide the respective image based on the screen size. The benefit to this approach is that you can reuse those classes for other scenarios. In addition, you can avoid having to set a height on the `a` element.

```
@media screen and (min-width:481px) {
    .hidden_desktop {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .hidden_mobile {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both solutions worked, but I´m using your second! But by the way, you change my media queries for others, do you think that mines are not correct?

Comment: @OzzC Your media queries are fine, I just did that for simplicity. Just use whatever media queries work for your content.

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers, we can use the `<picture>` and `<source>` in HTML to display different images based on media query

```
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width:480px)" srcset="your_picture_for_mobile.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px)" srcset="your_picture_for_tablet.jpg">
    <img src="your_picture_for_default.jpg" alt="picture-description">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have correct @media queries to do this.

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer kmike, but why that are the correct media queries? Sorry this answer, but Im still learning, and if there are some "rules to follow" maybe its better for me!